# Is there an opposite methods to `unittest.TestCase.fail()` to pass a Python unit test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, warnings, python-unittest

I am currently using this `self.assertTrue(True)` to pass the test. What I want is to pass a test if a specific warning is raised.

```
import warnings
class test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        with warning.catch_warnings(record=False):
            warning.simplefilter("error", category=CustomWarning)
            try: function_that_raisesCustomWarning()
            except CustomWarning as w: self.assertTrue(True)
```

Comment: You could just return from the function when the thing you want happens, and put a line afterwards that will cause a fail (if the return was not hit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A test always passes, in case there is no indication that it failed. Just don't do anything in case everything is alright.

Comment: True actually. I modified my codes into this to satisfy my needs. `try: function_that_raisesCustomWarning()\nCustomWarning as w: pass`.